# web3 solidity variable can't set value

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3py

My Code

https://gist.github.com/tlatkdgus1/4885faa14ca123024fbb3fd194404352

Result

https://gist.github.com/tlatkdgus1/e87c7f247fb3d0376613d25e8286ec80

Geth

https://gist.github.com/tlatkdgus1/5939f90a7b5c478f78c8ec0ecca45b5b

How can I set solidity variable value?

I tried these things:

1. solidity setInt (X)
2. gas increase (X)
3. solidity variable name change (X)

I think the problem is related to this but I'm not sure:

```
while w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash) is None:
    print (w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash))
```

Reference
https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py

Comment: And what is the problem...? You don't even give a word about it...

Comment: contract_instance.setLog('tlatk', '12', 'product',transact={'from': 
    w3.eth.coinbase,'gas':3000000})) this code is not work so return value is ''

Comment: Your question is not clear!

Answer (score 0):

Im answering the question that I think you are asking: why does `getLog` not return the values set in the earlier expression with `setLog`?

Answer:
The `setLog` transaction has not yet been mined by the time the the `getLog` call is made.

Ive cleaned up your code a bit for readability, and turned your `while` loop into a function with a timeout.  Ive also taken the liberty of making updates to use the web3.py v4 pre-release.

the web3.py pre-release (allong with eth_tester) can be installed with:

`$ pip install --pre web3[tester]`

```
import json
import time
from web3 import Web3
from web3.providers.eth_tester import EthereumTesterProvider
from solc import compile_source
from web3.contract import ConciseContract
import time

contract_source_code = '''
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract contract_log {
string name;
string time;
string product;

function contract_log(){
    name='kk';
    }
function setLog(string a, string b, string c) public {
    name = a;
    time = b;
    product = c;
    }


function getLog() constant returns (string, string, string) {
    return (name, time, product);
}

}
'''

def wait_on_tx_receipt(tx_hash):
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        if start_time + 60 < time.time():
            raise TimeoutError("Timeout occurred waiting for tx receipt")
        if w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash):
            return w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)


compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_source_code) # Compiled source code
contract_interface = compiled_sol['<stdin>:contract_log']

w3 = Web3(EthereumTesterProvider())

contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])

deploy_tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3.eth.coinbase, 'gas':500000})
contract_address = wait_on_tx_receipt(deploy_tx_hash).contractAddress
contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract_interface['abi'], address=contract_address)

tx_hash = contract_instance.functions.setLog(
    'tlatk',
    '12',
    'product').transact({'from':w3.eth.coinbase,'gas':500000})

wait_on_tx_receipt(tx_hash)

print(contract_instance.functions.getLog().call())
```